# Is it best to have HIPAA data pushed to me or to pull it and how do those solutions differ from an infrastructure and security perspective?

Tags: dmz, sftp

Long time reader first time asking.

I have HIPAA data I need to get from point A to point B. Point A can either securely host the file to be pulled by Point B or push the data to Point B. I am primarily interested in the overhead and security impact at Point B.

My understanding is if Point A were to push the file to Point B, best practices would be to have it dumped via SFTP in a secure location in Point B's DMZ and then pulled inside to Point B's secure zone.

If Point B were instead to pull the data from Point A via SFTP is it okay to pull directly into Point B's secure zone or should it make a stop in the DMZ first?

Ultimately I need to figure out if we need to set up an SFTP server at Point B or not.

Comment: Where are point A and point B located?  Is one a vendor or are they both locations you own?  I assume that you're getting a file from a vendor but that's not clear.